# How to evaluate to false instead of: "TypeError: Cannot read property"

Tags: javascript, json, conditional-operator

I am trying to use the questionmark/colon conditional operator to test a value in a JSON, and output a value in the JSON if true (true evaluated if the JSON property exists), and a default value if false.

Example:

```
data.children[0].preview ? data.children[0].preview.image.url : "https://defaulturl.com/etc/etc.jpg"
```

Whenever the value doesn't exist, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preview' of undefined".  I am wondering if there is a way to rewrite my conditional above that will evaluate the error as being 'false' so as to trigger the false action to be taken, and not be considered an error. Can this be done?

Just to note, my above code works as expected if the property exists.

Comment: I was able to use the hasOwnProperty() method and it seems to work, but I will be trying some of the other answers as well.

Comment: Also tested with optional chaining and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether `data.children[0]` exists before trying to access `.preview`:

```
(data.children[0] && data.children[0].preview) ? data.children[0].preview.image.url : "https://defaulturl.com/etc/etc.jpg"
```

In recent versions of JavaScript, you can use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator `?.`.

```
data.children[0]?.preview ? data.children[0].preview.image.url : "https://defaulturl.com/etc/etc.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modern **optional chaining** and **nullish coalescing** operators:

```
data.children?.[0]?.preview?.image?.url ?? "https://defaulturl.com/etc/etc.jpg"
```

If one of these properties is undefined the expression returns the default URL.